# Which is the faster or better way of sending large amounts of sensor data into QuestDB?

Tags: time-series, questdb

I have a large amount of streaming IoT sensor data and I'm using QuestDB as a time series database. I'm curious whether it's better to send this over Postgres or via Influx line protocol if I have a lot of measurements. I would like to use Python for this, if possible, but it depends which performs better.

Comment: What is meant by "large amounts"?

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB line protocol is designed for high-throughput ingestion. This interface is for write operations only, so you will still need to use PostgreSQL wire protocol or REST API for querying.

It's recommended then for your IoT / high-throughput scenario to use InfluxDB line protocol as this is the most efficient. There are Python examples for simple socket writes over TCP and UDP on [the official documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data#influxdb-line-protocol).